# HTML Centering text boxes

Tags: html, css, alignment

so I'm a new student to HTML and CSS learning to do basic modifications such as centring. I have a text box here and with it, a label. I'm trying to center the label and textbox on the center of the page, but while I've been able to do it with text, I have been struggling to do the same with the textbox. I've had the same issues with the radio buttons, for some reason text-align: center doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/69xfqo70/1/

What am I missing? I'm trying to get something like this:

```
                                                   Label 
                                           ______________________
                                          |______________________|

                                                   Label 
                                           ______________________
                                          |______________________|

                                                   Label 
                                           ______________________
                                          |______________________|


                                                 • option 1
                                                 • option 2
                                                 • option 3
```

^not sure if that came out right, but if not that's supposed to be at the center of the page

Comment: Try to provide codes in along with your question. Rather than giving it's link.

Comment: To center your labels simply make them `inline-block` rather than `inline`. To center your `.textboxes`, do the same, then use `margin`. Or alternatively use flexbox or CSS Grid.